# multiple if statement not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use two different IF statements to get time stamp on different columns as soon as a specific column is edited. For example, on any edit in column 1 time stamp should appear in column 3 and edit in column 10 should result in time stamp in column 13.

But what is happening is as soon as the column 1 is edited both time stamps are getting updated.

the code is as follows:

```
function onEdit(){
  var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var currentSheet=spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var actRange=currentSheet.getActiveRange();
  var rowIndex=actRange.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex=actRange.getColumn();

      if((colIndex=1) && (rowIndex>1)){
        currentSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 3).setValue(new Date());
        }  
      if((colIndex=10) && (rowIndex>1)){
         currentSheet.getRange(rowIndex, 13).setValue(new Date());
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is an assignment operator not a comparison operator.

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e){
  if((e.range.columnStart==1 || e.range.columnStart==10) && (e.range.rowStart>1)){
    e.range.offset(0,3).setValue(new Date());
  }  
}
```

- [Expression and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: I do it all the time.

Comment: I would put some page conditionals on that script otherwise it will run on any page in the spreadsheet.

Comment: nice idea for the future, but this one is supposed to run on all the sheets. Thanks again, man!!!